# Pulling variable from HTML output to PHP send email

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, contact-form

I bought a web template for my startup company.

The template uses php to use contact form. The thing I want to do is implement "volume calculator" outcome to contact form.

In the code of "volume calculator" the results are tagged as "RsltMax" "RsltMin"

I don't know if it's allowed but here's the website : [www.wiseremovals.com/quotation_2.html](http://www.wiseremovals.com/quotation_2.html)
at the bottom you can see the "volume calculator"

with those id's I tried to add this to .php script

```
$RsltMax = $_POST["RsltMax"];


$message .= "\nVolume: " . $RsltMax;
```

Even though now I receive a line in email with Volume the outcome is empty.

Edit :
Here's the how the calculator works (just one item)

```
 <div class="dv1">
                                <span class="spn1">Üçlü Koltuk</span>
                                <div hmax="2.15" hmin="1.46" id="sln1" class="countr">0</div>
                                <a class="angtf" title="Çıkar" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="fn_SlctObjct('-1','sln1')">-</a>
                                <a class="apls" title="Ekle" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="fn_SlctObjct('1','sln1')">+</a>
                            </div>
```

the code ends with

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout(function () { fn_LoadHcm(); }, 0);
        </script>
```

And Fn_load is "RsltMax" and "RsltMin" and here's how they calculated.

```
 id('RsltMax').innerHTML = "max:  " + var_Max;
    id('RsltMin').innerHTML = "min:  " + var_Min;
```

Kindly remember I'm not a coder myself, just have a basic understanding of HTML and CSS to manipulate to website to my needs however these php thing is way out of my knowledge.

Comment: `I'm not a coder myself`....per the [tour]: _"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers"_ . Being realistic, as a non-programmer you may struggle to answer our requests for extra info / clarification, struggle to provide the right code to form a [mre] of your issue, and struggle to understand what to do with any answers you may receive. See also [ask] as well. Also we're not here to replace your complete lack of expertise (because you can pay a freelancer for that), the idea is to co-operate to create useful programming questions and answers.

Comment: If you've observed that `$_POST["RsltMax"]` doesn't contain the value you expect, your next step is to check how/if that value is being passed to the server in the first place.  For example, is this a `<form>` being submitted?  Something else?  Where/how is that value included?

Comment: `I don't know if it's allowed but here's the website`.... see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @David thanks for the only helpfull comment. I'll check and try to learn about that. But to answer your question that value calculated via external Javascript

Comment: @Blaberus: Whether the value is calculated by code client-side or entered by the user client-side probably isn't important.  I wouldn't keep focusing on that unless debugging the code has provided some compelling reason to do so.  What *is* important is how data is being sent to the server in the given request and whether or not that value is being included in that request to the server.  As an example, if a `<form>` is being submitted but that value is outside of the `<form>` or not in a standard form element then that would be why it isn't included.

Comment: If it's calculated via external JavaScript then it may not be submitted as part of your form data. That depends on what the JS does with it afterwards, and how the form is submitted. As previously noted, we would need to see a [mre] of the issue containing all the (relevant) code, in order to pinpoint the exact source of the problem, and the exact solution

Comment: Dear @ADyson , thanks for trying to help. Since the volume calculator contains 3 javascripts and a html file posting the whole code and the comment section has only 500 character limit how may i share it with you ?

Comment: Code doesn't belong in the comments, they are just for brief discussion and clarification. You need to [edit] your question to make major updates annd provide more info. Also...as mentioned above, we don't really want the code of your entire page - just a [mre] of the specific issue please, then we don't have to wade through mountains of irrelevant stuff to find what's important. Thanks :-)

Comment: @ADyson Thanks again! I have edited to thread. For your first comments ; I bought the templates and scripts because I respect the job people do. This is for startup usage I wish to work with freelancer in the future. If there was many problem or integrations needed I wouldn't seek help online with the little knowledge I have since it would basically asking for free consultation which is wrong in my book.

Comment: @Blaberus: Given the updated code, I don't see anything shown here which would post a value called "RsltMax" to the server.  There's no `<form>` at all, and no JavaScript shown which is making an AJAX request or anything of that nature.  If the JavaScript code is simply updating some display value on the front-end (we don't know for certain, but it looks that way so far) then that doesn't really have anything to do with sending a value to the server.  So far there's yet to be any expectation that `$_POST["RsltMax"]` should have any value in it at all.

Comment: I would agree. There seems to be some custom code here, but I'd assume `id('RsltMax')` hides `document.getElementById("RsltMax");` or similar. And we can't see what kind of HTML element the one with the ID `RsltMax` is, because you haven't shown it. However, since the output is being written to that element using `innerHTML`, I'd assume it's not a form element which would get submitted to the server, but simply something like a `div` or `span` which is purely for display. (Form elements generally have a `value` property that you would set if you wanted to update it.)

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Even though the "volume calculator" starts with <form> tag the id 'RsltMax' is different than other section since all other sections are typed as input. I'm really thankful for your helps but if solving this requires complete new way of calculation I'm simply thinking the removing the volume calculator from page and putting a button for modal which people can calculate manually and input the output manually even though this is not something I would want I feel like I'm wasting your time here.

Comment: You could just modify it slightly so it also writes the calculated values into two hidden fields in the form which have the correct `name` attributes which php is expecting